# WPF Program - program is not valid win32

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp

I have create a Small WPF C# Program with VS2012. it is run successful in Win 7 and Win 8 , 32Bit and 64bit
but it have trouble with windows XP and after runnig exe file This message is displayed:
program is not valid win32
What is the solution?

Comment: Are you getting the error while installing the application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should reduce the target framework of your Project. VS2012 runs with .NET 4.5 as default, Windows XP does not support anything higher than .NET 4.0.

You can go to your Project Properties and select at the tab `Application` the Target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try the workaround mentioned in the following link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx

But still you need to open up to us to give accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed .Net framework in target machine. Windows XP does not support .NET 4.0 and higher

Comment: Am I just not believing this that Windows XP does not even support .NET 4.0 or did you mean "XP does not support .NET Framework _higher_ than 4.0"?

Comment: .Net 4.0 is supported on Windows XP Service Pack 3. Anything higher is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to this, just make sure the platform target of the program is not x64 if you are running it in a 32 bit machine. .Net framework 4 should work in windows XP machine.